vertically center the contents of a cell in a tabular, where the cell width is unknown
How do I vertically center the contents of a cell in a tabular, where I don't know the width of the cell. The array package offers an m{<width>} column type, but I can't get it to work with unknown widths.
For example, how would I vertically center the text in the following table? This seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but I've been grappling with it for a few days and can't seem to find an answer that works for my specific situation.
In my actual document, I run into this issue twice. One is where I try to vertically center an aligned environment next to a tikzpicture. In the other, I try to vertically center a smaller tikzpicture next to a bigger one.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\rule{2cm}{5cm} & something that I don't know the width of \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



You don't show the pictures, but the idea should work the same: the key is
baseline=(current bounding box.center)

Example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
\begin{tikzcd}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}
&
$\begin{aligned}
a &= b+c \\
x+y &= u+v
\end{aligned}$
\\
\midrule
\begin{tikzcd}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}
&
\begin{tikzcd}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
A \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B \arrow[d] \\
C \arrow[r] & D \\
E \arrow[u] \arrow[ur]
\end{tikzcd}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Thank you, this works for my purposes. I would mention that the reason I didn't share the images is because I am only a collaborator, and don't feel it is appropriate to share work I do not own.
